# how to map multiple records to one unique id

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 data sets with a common unique ID(duplicates in 2nd data frame)
I want to map all records with respect to each ID.

```
df1     
id      
1        
2        
3        
4        
5        

df2
id   col1
1   mango
2   melon
1   straw
3   banana
3   papaya
```

i want the out put like

```
df1         
id  col1    
1   mango
    straw
2   melon   
3   banana
    papaya         
4   not available
5   not available
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the output `df1` what `id` does the `straw` value have?  Is it also `1`?  Or are `mango` & `straw` in a list?  Or is something else going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking to do an outer [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, how='outer').set_index('id').fillna('not available')

>>> df1

             col1
id               
1           mango
1           straw
2           melon
3          banana
3          papaya
4   not available
5   not available
```

Comment: Would love some feedback regarding the downvote! Not sure if I misunderstood the question, or whether this is a legitimately bad solution to OP's problem?

Comment: It seems fine to me, in fact I was going to post a similar answer.  It's not clear how OP want's to deal with duplicates, maybe `.groupby('id')['col1'].apply(list)`?  (Optionally, with a `.to_frame()`)

Comment: @AaronN.Brock, yeah, that could make sense, although in OP's wanted output, each has duplicate has its own row.